# Identify an animal (Japan, urban area)

Tags: species-identification, zoology

I met this animal yesterday while walking along a small river in Yokohama, Japan. It came out of the bushes some 5 meters away from me, but while I was launching the camera app on my smartphone, it already went away into a fenced area where I couldn't follow and was quite far, so these are the best pictures I could take. It seemed to have something wrong with it's fur (either molting or sick). Could be a japanese raccoon dog (a.k.a. tanuki), although the images I found on Google don't look much like it to my untrained eye (maybe because of the fur), or some kind of a fox (looked even less likely). Tried asking locals, but they tend not to know anything about animals, unless those animals are either dogs, cats or foods. So, what is this?
[image]
EDIT: the size is hard to describe, I would say, it was a bit bigger than a big domestic cat, and also had different proportions - longer body, neck and legs.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include an estimate for the size of this mammal. A description of what you could observe about its coat/skin might also help. ——— You may also want to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to narrow it down to 3 species in Musteloidea, the weasel superfamily, but I think you observed a Tanuki that was suffering from scabies.

1) Tanuki / Japanese raccoon dog - 'Tanuki' - (Nyctereutes procyonoides viverrinus).
Visually similar to what you observed. The feet and face in particular seems to fit with a tanuki. Tanuki are often observed in urban areas in Japan and have been increasing in recent years. There are frequent reports of tanuki with scabies that have missing fur and a similar appearance:
(Google search for "tanuki" and "scabies":
https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%96%A5%E7%99%AC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%8C%E3%82%AD

2) Common raccoon - 'Araiguma' - (Procyon lotor)
Since they were introduced in 1962 as pets, there are some wild populations in Japan, including in Kanagawa prefecture where you observed the animal.

3) Japanese badger - 'Anaguma' - (Meles anakuma)
Another possibility but I think it does not fit your observation.

There are a few other species in this superfamily but I think it is safe to exclude them due to a lack of visual similarity.